# apache ScriptAlias cgi-bin directory

Tags: apache, cgi, fedora

this has been a problem for me for days and I haven't been able to solve it.

I'm working on fedora 14 and using Apache/2.2.17 (Unix)

the document root is `/var/www` and it is well configured in my `httpd.conf`

I have several folders inside `/var/www` that have perl files that require CGI to be run and instead, sometimes the perl file is offered as download and sometimes an error 500 appears

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

the cgi_module is being loaded and even if I use ScriptAlias, and the directory tag, the file is still not being ran a script.

I even tried to create a virtual host and it doesnt work.

For instance, if I want a directory called "pyl" located inside the apache root (`/var/www`) what would the lines for `httpd.conf` be?

Comment: Have you looked at the server's error log?

Comment: I did and actually there is no log of it. I gave up and in the meantime Im using nginx (just in case anyone wants to try it... now my problem is with perl itself)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, check the error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` ?), check your file and dir permissions.

Also make sure your `ScriptAlias` directive is updated correctly.

So, have a look in your site config file (i.e. `sites-available/default`) and change this:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
```

.. to this:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
```

.. and reload apache2.

Answer (score 3):

This solution applies to Apache2.4.51 version or may others. The directory structure can change with versions.

1. Make a change the default CGI config file below:

   ```
   nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
   ```

   Change:

   ```
   ScriptAlias /cgi/ /home/user/your-folder
                <Directory "/home/user/your-folder">
   ```
2. Move your `*.cgi`, `*.py`, `*.sh`, etc files to your folder
3. Apply `chmod 755` to your folder:

   ```
   chmod 755 /your-folder
   ```
4. Restart apache2:

   ```
   systemctl restart apache2
   ```

Sample pyhton code that you can run:

```
nano /home/user/your-folder/pythonapp.py
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Content-type:text/html")
print()
print("""
        <!doctype html>
        <html><head></head><title>CGI-Python</title>
        <body> Python App </body>
        </html>
        """)
```

Save and run your url:

```
server-ip-or-host/cgi/pythonapp.py
```